# Making a substitution in an ODE to solve with Bessel's functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm reviewing from a course I took last year in ordinary and partial differential equations (the name of the course is Advanced Engineering Math II, but I figure that's not very descriptive).

I have an ODE whose general solution can be written in terms of Bessel functions if I make a specific substitution.  I can tell that the original equation is not immediately in a form solved by Bessel functions, and I know what to expect when I make the substitution.  So I think I'm making an error in the substitution step, but I haven't figured out where.

The ODE is (where $y$ is a function of $x$):

$$4x^2y'' + 4xy' + (x - 9)y = 0$$

And the given substition is to let $$z = \sqrt{x}$$

<del>I can see that the 9x^3 is the reason for needing the substition;  if it were 9x^2, I'd be in business.</del>

So I started making the substitution.

If $z = \sqrt{x}$ then $x = z^2$.  Let's substitute in a new function of $z$, called $w$.

Then $y(x) = w(z^2)$

And $y'(x) = 2zw'(z^2)$ (by the chain rule)

And $y''(x) = 4z^2w''(z^2) + 2w'(z^2)$

<del>So now I substitue w in for y and z in for x to get
4(z^2)^2[4z^2w'' + 2w'] + 4(z^2)[2zw'] + (9(z^2)^3 - 36)[w] = 0</del>

<del>The next step I perform is to group terms by w, w', and w''.
16z^6w'' + (8z^4 + 8z^3)w' + (9z^6 - 36)w</del>

<del>Now I see that I have a problem, because my $w'$ term has both z^4 and z^3.  This doesn't look very much like the Bessel equation I was expecting.</del>  The back of the book says I should get $$z^2y'' + zy' + (z^2 - 9)y = 0$$  which looks very much like a Bessel equation to me.  Once I get to this point I know that I can have a solution using the special $J_\nu(z)$.  I probably made a mistake in the substitution, but I'm not sure exactly where.

The only other thought I had is that I shouldn't be changing the derivatives of $y$, and only substitute for $x$.  But that doesn't seem right because a) I'll still have the wrong powers of $x$ or $z$ and b) it doesn't seem mathematically sound to change the "free" $x$'s, but not $y$, a function of $x$, and say it's equivalent.

So where has my substitution gone wrong?

**Edit:** I had spliced two problems together.  I've updated the original problem, and will update my steps later today.

*Textbook:  Advanced Engineering Mathematics, by Peter V. O'Neil, 7th edition, Cengage, 2012.  Section 15.3 Problem 11.  (I picked an odd one because I knew I could check my work.  I tried number 13 and had similar issues)*

Comment: See a related [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652907/questions-concerning-the-differential-operator/652945#652945).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I'm not sure I understand the connection. Are you suggesting that I take find $w'$ by taking $(dw/dz) * (dz/dx)$?

Comment: Are you sure about the answer from the back of the book? The $(z^{2}-9)$ term isn't multiplied by $y$?

Comment: @PaulSafier Good catch...I wrote it down wrong.  I also realized while looking at it again that I wrote parts of two different problems down.  I need to update my steps with the new problem, but don't have time to do it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $$dy/dx=(dy/dz)*(dz/dx)=1/2z*dy/dz$$ similarly $$d^2y/dx^2=d/dx*(dy/dx)=d/dx(1/2z*dy/dz)
=1/4z^2*d^2y/dz^2-1/4z^3*dy/dz$$ now by inserting $dy/dx$ and $d^2y/dx^2$ with $x^2=z^4$ in the original problem (equation) and just simplify by using a little algebra you will get your answer...

Comment: This is what I wound up doing.  I had forgotten this was still up here.  My real issue was trying to put two different problems in one, but this is useful for people who don't mess up copying the problem down :)