# general solution of elastic beam equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the following equation;

$t^4 \dfrac{d^2u}{dt^2} + \lambda^2 u = 0, \quad \lambda >0, ~ t>0,$

where $u(t)$ is real valued function. by using the change of variables

$t=\dfrac{1}{\tau} , \quad u(t)=\dfrac{v(\tau)}{\tau} ,$

how can we find the general solution of the above equation.

Comment: Have you tried using that change of variables?

Comment: " http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x^4+y%27%27+%2B+a^2+y+%3D+0 "

Comment: sorry couldn't read

Comment: Compute $\frac{du}{dt}$ as functions of $\tau$ and $\frac{du}{d\tau}$.Then compute $\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}$ as well. Then put them into the equation.

Comment: Well, I used the change of variable: thus $\dfrac{d^2v}{d \tau^2} \dfrac{1}{\tau} + \lambda^2 \dfrac{v}{\tau}=0$

Comment: thus, general solution is $v(\tau)=C_1 e^{\lambda^2 \tau} + C_2 e^{- \lambda^2 \tau} =C_1 e^{\lambda^2 1/t} + C_2 e^{- \lambda^2 1/t}  $... is it true?

Comment: You need to use the change of variables which you have been given. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652907/questions-concerning-the-differential-operator) for how you do that.

Comment: Hi hayrit ! your ODE is exact and can be more simplified. But your solution $v(\tau)$ is not correct. Sinusoidal functions of $\lambda\tau$ are involved (or exponentials with $i\lambda \tau$ in the argument, not $\lambda^2\tau$).

Comment: if I write $v^{''}+\lambda^2 v=0$, and roots are: $0$ and $-\lambda^2$. thus the general solution is $v=C_1+C_2 e^{-\lambda^2 \tau}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

This shows a method to carry out the change of variable and the change of function, as requested in the wording. Then, you can solve the ODE which is obtained on a well-known form :

[image]